# Creating function with jquery data attribute

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a function in jQuery based on the data attr.

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" data-validate="validatename" />

$("#name").blur(function(){
    var validate = $(this).attr("data-validate");
    var newvalidate = validate+"()";
    newvalidate;
});

function validatename(){
   alert("success"); 
}
```

Debugging gives the value of `newvalidate` as `validatename()` but the function doesn't run. How can i make this work?

Comment: Try, `window[validate]()` instead of introducing `newValidate`.

Comment: What are you expecting `validate+"()";` to do, because I doubt it's what you are thinking it is (*it's just a string*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because it's not a function, `newvalidate` is just the string with the value of `"validatename()"` and nothing more. To run a global function which you have the name as a string you can do `window[validate]()` :

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" data-validate="validatename" />

$("#name").blur(function(){
    var validate = $(this).attr("data-validate");
    window[validate]();
});

function validatename(){
   alert("success"); 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Creating a string that ends with `()` won't cause the function to be executed. To execute a string as if it's Javascript code, you need to call `eval()`:

```js
$("#name").blur(function(){
    var validate = $(this).attr("data-validate");
    var newvalidate = validate+"()";
    eval(newvalidate);
});

function validatename(){
   alert("success"); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" data-validate="validatename" />
```

You could also just look up the name in the global scape to get the function itself and call it.

```
window[validate]()
```

Comment: You don't need to use `eval()` here.

Comment: You don't need to, but it's one way to do it.

Comment: Yes it's a way you can do, but it's never a good idea to use `eval` that's subject to user input. Especially when it's not necessary and is likely slower.

Comment: But this isn't user input, it's an attribute from the HTML.